# VaadinSession attribute and updating session-bound components

Tags: vaadin, custom-component, vaadin-session

I have a Vaadin **Navigator** with multiple **View** elements. Each view has a different purpose however some also contain common traits that I have put inside custom components.

One of those custom components is the menu - it is positioned at the top and allows navigation between the different views. I create and add this component inside the constructor of each view (if you are interested in the menu's implementation see the end of this post). Here is a skeleton for each custom view:

```
class MyViewX implements View {

  MenuViewComponent mvc;

  public MyViewX() {
    mvc = new MenuViewComponent();
    addComponent(mvc);
  }

  @Override
  public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
  }
}
```

So far, so good. In order to make things simple I will explain my problem using a simple label and not one of my other custom components but the dependency that I will describe here is the same for those components just like with the label.

Let's say I have a label which sole purpose is to display a greeting with the user's username. In order to do that I use **VaadinSession** where I store the attribute. This is done by my **LoginController**, which validates the user by looking into a database and if the user is present, the attribute is set and one of the views is opened automatically. The problem is that `VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("username")` returns `null` when called inside the constructor. This of course makes sense omho because a constructor should not be bound by a session-attribute.

So far I have managed to use the `enter()` method where there is no problem in retrieving session attributes:

```
class MyViewX implements View {

  MenuViewComponent mvc;

  public MyViewX() {
    mvc = new MenuViewComponent();
    addComponent(mvc);
  }

  @Override
  public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    String username = (String)VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("username");
    Label greeting = new Label("Hello " + username);
    addComponent(greeting);
  }
}
```

The issue that comes from this is obvious - whenever I open the view where this label is present, a new label is added so if I re-visit the view 10 times, I will get 10 labels. Even if I move the label to be a class member variable the `addComponent(...)` is the one that screws things up. Some of my custom components really depend on the `username` attribute (in order to display user-specific content) hence I also have to place those in the `enter(...)` method. The `addComponent(...)` makes a mess out of it. I even tried the dirty way of removing a component and then re-adding it alas! in vain:

```
class MyViewX implements View {

  MenuViewComponent mvc;
  Label greeting;

  public MyViewX() {
    mvc = new MenuViewComponent();
    addComponent(mvc);
  }

  @Override
  public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    String username = (String)VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("username");
    greeting = new Label("Hello " + username);

    // Remove if present
    try { removeComponent(greeting); }
    catch(Exception ex) { }

    // Add again but with new content
    addComponent(greeting);
  }
}
```

but it's still not working. So my question is: **what is the simplest way of updating a component that requires session-bound attributes?**

The navigation via the menu custom component is omho not the issue here since all components of the menu are loaded in it's constructor. That's why it's also load that component in particular in a view's own constructor. Here is an example of a button in my menu that opens a view:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@PreserveOnRefresh
public class MenuViewComponent extends CustomComponent {
  public MenuViewComponent(boolean adminMode) {
    HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
    Label title = new Label("<h2><b>Vaadin Research Project</b></h2>");
    title.setContentMode(ContentMode.HTML);
    layout.addComponent(title);
    layout.setComponentAlignment(title, Alignment.TOP_LEFT);

    Button personalDashboardButton = new Button("Personal dashboard", new Button.ClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(MainController.PERSONALDASHBOARDVIEW);
      }
    });

    personalDashboardButton.setStyleName(BaseTheme.BUTTON_LINK);
    layout.addComponent(personalDashboardButton);
    layout.setComponentAlignment(personalDashboardButton, Alignment.TOP_CENTER);

    // Add other buttons for other views

    layout.setSizeUndefined();
    layout.setSpacing(true);
    setSizeUndefined();
    setCompositionRoot(layout);
  }
}
```

`PERSONALDASHBOARDVIEW` is just one of the many views I have.

Comment: Why not simply have the label created only once `Label greeting = new Label()` and in your `enter` method set its value `greeting.setValue("Hello " + username)`. Also `@PreserveOnRefresh` is intended for use with an UI object.

Comment: Custom component is an UI object (see [here](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/CustomComponent.html)). As for setting the `setValue()` - please note that Label here was used (as I've also mentioned in the question) as an example. It's the connection here between session attribute and a UI component that is important and not `setValue()` or similar things. I have multiple custom components that generate much more complex content based only on the `username` attribute (including accessing the underlying database via controllers bound to the components and views).

Comment: I was referring to the [UI itself](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html). Regarding your components, depending on your needs I see at least the following 2 possibilities: 1) recreate the whole view content each time a user enters it 2) have a state variable, say `boolean viewWasVisited = false`. If it's false initialize the content and set it to `true`, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: Ah, okay. Ahm, can elaborate more on 1) and 2). The full recreation of a view sounds as an overkill (especially since I have components that are not bound to the session such as a dynamically generated table and chart (using a bunch of tables in my DB)). As for the flag: once you add a component to the view if the component doesn't offer `setValue()` or similar functionality the only way of updating it is to remove it and add it again (which leads to my problem...). If I use `addComponent()` once but change the `Label` object with the `new` operator every time will this update the UI or not?

Comment: No it will not, the old object will be referenced by your container as you added it with `addComponent()` and your field will reference a different new object each time. Think about this, it's like you'd do `List<Person> users = new ArrayList<>(); Person person = new Person("A"); users.add(person); person = new Person("B");` The list will hold a person with name A while you will create a new one with name B. However `person.setName("B")` will work. Anyway, as far as I know all Vaadin components can be updated after being created, and you can design your own components this way from the get-go.

Comment: Can you post this as answer. It works like a charm. One-time trigger for adding the components and then re-creating the objects they contains - very nice results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be worth considering how long should your view instances "live", just as long they're displayed, until the session ends or a mix of the two. With this in mind and depending on what needs to happen when you enter/re-enter a view, you have at least the following 3 options:

**1) Recreate the whole view** (allowing for early view garbage-collection)

- first register a [ClassBasedViewProvider](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.navigator.html#advanced.navigator.navigating.viewprovider) (instead of a StaticViewProvider) which does not hold references to the created views:

  ```
  navigator = new Navigator(this, viewDisplay);
  navigator.addProvider(new Navigator.ClassBasedViewProvider(MyView.NAME, MyView.class));
  ```
- simple view implementation

  ```
  public class MyView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

      public static final String NAME = "myViewName";

      @Override
      public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
          // initialize tables, charts and all the other cool stuff
          addComponent(new SweetComponentWithLotsOfStuff());
      }
  }
  ```

**2) Keep some already created components and replace others**

```
public class MyView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    private MySweetComponentWithLotsOfStuff mySweetComponentWithLotsOfStuff;

    public MyView() {
        // initialize only critical stuff here or things that don't change on enter
        addComponent(new MyNavigationBar());
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
        // oh, so the user does indeed want to see stuff. great, let's do some cleanup first
        removeComponent(mySweetComponentWithLotsOfStuff);

        // initialize tables, charts and all the other cool stuff
        mySweetComponentWithLotsOfStuff = new SweetComponentWithLotsOfStuff();

        // show it
        addComponent(mySweetComponentWithLotsOfStuff);
    }
}
```

**3) Lazy creating and updating (or not) the content when entering**

```
public class MyView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    private boolean isFirstDisplay = true;
    private MySweetComponentWithLotsOfStuff mySweetComponentWithLotsOfStuff;

    public MyView() {
        // initialize only critical stuff here, as the user may not even see this view
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
        // oh, so the user does indeed want to see stuff
        if (isFirstDisplay) {
            isFirstDisplay = false;
            // lazily initialize tables, charts and all the other cool stuff
            mySweetComponentWithLotsOfStuff = new SweetComponentWithLotsOfStuff();
            addComponent(mySweetComponentWithLotsOfStuff);
        } else {
            // maybe trigger component updates, or simply don't do anything
            mySweetComponentWithLotsOfStuff.updateWhateverIsRequired();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure (and curious) that there may be other options, but I've mainly used a variation of 1) using spring with prototype views and component tabs.

Comment: I did the one-time trigger since it happens to be (at least omho) the best in terms of performance. I also applied this for the VaadinSession attribute retrieval itself. I created a controller for one of my views and retrieved the `username` there. The controller itself was added with this one-time trigger inside the `enter()` method. Real neat solution. Thanks again!

Comment: @rbaleksandar No problem, glad to help